# make a number of lines of string into one long line in python

Tags: python, string

Say i had the string:

```
string = '''
this line number 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
'''
```

How would you make it into:

```
this is line number 1line 2line 3line4
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `join` and `splitlines`:

```
>>> string = '''
... this line number 1
... line 2
... line 3
... line 4
... '''
>>> ''.join(string.splitlines())
'this line number 1line 2line 3line 4'
```

This is better than a `.replace("\n", "")` because it deals with `\r\n` *and* `\n`:

```
>>> "".join("a\r\nb\nc".splitlines())
'abc'
>>> "a\r\nb\nc".replace("\n", "")
'a\rbc'
```

Comment: I don't know why everyone jumps to `''.join` - that is not the pythonic way to do everything!

Comment: @manoj: Why? Where does it say that? And define what constitutes *Pythonic* here?

Comment: @sukhbir - I am just saying there is a simpler way to do this. Why the unnecessary splitlines and then join? Simple job complicated.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the `\r\n` vs `\n` problem.

Comment: So we give downvotes for non-Pythonic code now?  Does this only apply to questions about Python, or are my javascript questions going to get downvoted for being non-Pythonic?

Comment: @Jeff And by pythonic, I meant ''.join being used in many places in Python, but it is not the appropriate one here.

Comment: @Jeff - I did not downvote for non pythonic. In fact, this is very much Pythonic, but being used to solve a simpler problem

Comment: @manojilds I have added explanation of why your solution is inadequate.

Comment: @manojlds No offense intended, but no one should have their answer downvoted when the answer WORKS

Comment: @bradley.ayers - no triple quotes string ( verbatim? ) don't have `\r\n`

Comment: Try to explain it in plain words. You would probably say "join the single lines" and not "replace the line breaks with something else". So the split/join version is much more explicit, which is very pythonic in my opinion.

Comment: @Achim - guys, I did not say the code was not Pythonic. I just said don't use it for everything. I have updated my answer. Phew, I shouldn't have used the word Pythonic. Please note the `everything` in my comment

Comment: @manojilds this method works regardless of how you get the data. Using one method if you're using triple quotes, and another if you're reading from a file, is not ideal.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - but that was not the question the OP asked. But atleast I ask you to remove the downvote on my answer.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - removed the downvote. I probably should not have downvoted in the first place, and sorry about the confusions on Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
string.replace("\n","")
```

Update:

It is wrong to consider that the string will contain `\r\n`. The triple quoted string will not contain `\r`, irrespective of the platform. But as @bradley.ayers says it is probably safer and practical to use `splitlines()`.

Below is the code with CRLF shown in Notepad++:

[image]

The above code works on Windows.

Comment: See my answer for why this isn't suitable.

Comment: @bradley.ayers - no triple quotes string ( verbatim? ) don't have `\r\n` .

Answer (score 1):

[Python String Replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

```
 print mystr.replace('\n', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '''
this line number 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
'''.replace('\n', '')

print s
```

Results in:

```
this line number 1line 2line 3line 4
```